# Unable to retrieve string value from strings.xml to Java

Tags: android

simple question . I got this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">YYYYYY</string>
    <string name="leaderBoard">XXXXX</string>
</resources>
```

in my res>values>strings.xml

Then in my Activity I try to pull out the leaderBoard value but java refuses to do so.

```
String string = getString(R.string.leaderBoard);
```

**leaderBoard cannot be resolved into a field.**

I have tried , cleaning up project , refreshing , still nothing.
On the other hand I am able to retrieve app_name into an xml file like the manifest.xml . I m pretty sure that I m blind or something...

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >       
         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
...
```

Comment: is your R.java file is properly updating? Also see the import. And use getResource().getString(R.string.leaderBoard);

Comment: Thanks for swift response , yes it was a noobish fault after all , Bojan was correct in my case.

Comment: you welcome as i said see your import, well we all make small mistakes after all. Happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct **R** class - the one of your project, not android's. Check the imports.

It should be something like this

```
import com.yourapp.R;
```

and not like

```
import android.R;
```

Comment: Your answer could be better explained to simply *NOT* import `android.R`. Under normal circumstances there should be no need to explicitly import your own `R.java` class as it is done implicitly for all classes within the same package.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read string form **String.xml** so you can use g`etString()` which is the method of resource so you will get your output Now.

**`getResources().getString(R.string.YOUR_XML_STRING);`**

If not works Please `Clean & Rebuild` your project

For More Info. You may visit

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html
>   And 
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.leaderBoard);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this

```
getResources().getString(R.string.leaderBoard);
```